# Нажатие на элемент, обернутый ссылкой

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на `<span>` срабатывало событие `onclick` без перехода по ссылке?

```
<a href="www.com.com">
  <span onclick="openSociety()">14</span>
  Dapibus ac facilisis in
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Передать в обработчик `event` и вызвать

```
event.preventDefault()
```

Comment: Нужно при нажатии на слова в ссылке переходить по ссылке, а при нажатии на <span>  - onclick. Так получится?

Comment: @Влад, я уже ответил на вопрос.